# Dependency Error jekyll-figure

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

When I run bundle exec jekyll serve I get following error message

```
Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-figure or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-figure' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
jekyll 3.4.0 | Error:  jekyll-figure
```

I added gem to gemfile and did a bundle install …Still got error message
Any way to fix this, Thanks.

Gemfile

```
source “https://rubygems.org”
ruby RUBY_VERSION

# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
gem "jekyll", "3.4.0"
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
gem 'jekyll-figure'



# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

config file

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site settings
title: Name
email: contact@domainname.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"

baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

twitter_username: 
github_username:  
owner:
  name:           Name
  avatar:         images/Your_image.jpg
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
exclude: ["README.md"]
sass:
    load_paths:
        - _sass
        - bs
paginate: 10
paginate_path: "page:num"
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-figure
```

Output of `bundle exec jekyll build --verbose --trace`
      Logging at level: debug
    Configuration file: /home/justinechacko/Web/govtexam/_config.yml
             Requiring: jekyll-figure
      Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-figure or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-figure' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
    /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:53:in `rescue in block in require_with_graceful_fail': jekyll-figure (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:41:in`block in require_with_graceful_fail'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:40:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:40:in`require_with_graceful_fail'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:27:in `require_gems'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in`conscientious_require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:111:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:33:in`initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:28:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:28:in`process'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in`block in execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in`execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in`program'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in`load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `'

Please look into this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Things look proper.. What is the output for **`bundle exec jekyll build --verbose --trace`**?

Comment: @ashmaroli I have added more code from `bundle exec jekyll build --verbose --trace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the structure of the plugin gem.
Simply change your `_config.yml` to load `jekyll/figure` instead..

```
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll/figure
```

Comment: How to check my gem is loaded?

Comment: `{% figure %}![Image](/path/to/image.jpg){% endfigure %}` should render without issues..